# why I don't see my page layout in all page layouts when editing a page online (office 365)

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer, office365

I have created a page layout from `Site Setting -> Design Manager -> Edit Page Layout -> Create New Page Layout`

Its conversion was successful but I can't find an option to do the followings:

- Add a new page with this new page layout
- Change the page layout of an existing page to this newly created page layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Publishing infrastructure activated, you must to checkout/checkin/publish in order to the master/layout begin selectable at page creation.

You can accomplish that both, using SharePoint Designer or Site->settings->master page and layouts.